# Video output only in live Usb and recovery

Tags: drivers, 20.04, display-resolution, amdgpu

I have an old machine with win 10 installed, but 20H2 update is incompatible with the GPU drivers, specs below:

> - Intel core 2 duo E6850 (2 cores, 3.00GHz)
> - asus p5k3 deluxe motherboard
> - 4GB of ddr3 ram, 1333MHz
> - radeon X1800XT, 512MB
> - 20GB segate barracuda IDE
> - 450 Watt antec PSU

I was forced to use the generic display driver which is pretty bad, so I decided to install lubuntu, as I have an older MacBook with it and it works well.

The live of 20.04.2 worked out of the box at full resolution and with no graphic glitches, so I installed the OS but after reboot, I only saw the loading screen at full resolution, then "no input" on the monitor. The system took the inputs, as I managed to shutdown, but no output on the monitor.

Tried booting in recovery, installed updates than started the desktop from recovery which worked at very low resolution. Rebooted but still no output.
Tried Linux lite and Elementary OS (Which worked on this system a couple of years back) but again the installer worked fine and no video output on regular boot.
I suspect is a 20.04 problem, at this point, because all of these distro are Ubuntu based.
Any suggestions? Maybe tomorrow I'll try with Debian or manjaro to see if the problem is only about Ubuntu, but I ask because it's strange that the live works and than the installation not.

Note: HDD's health is fine, and I tried also on a SATA HDD and didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried GA version of 20.04 LTS from http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/20.04/ubuntu-20.04-desktop-amd64.iso ?

Comment: I'm sorry for bringing up the bad news but any "Radeon X....." is simply too old for ANY currently supported OS including Ubuntu and flavors.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers! Tried GA version of 20.04, but didn't work, tried 18.04 but no luck, and finally tried experimental drivers but again it didn't work.
Installed Debian latest version through netinstall and it worked out of the box. I think that's because default debian doesn't install proprietary microcode for the GPU, which is a good thing in my case. Maybe this weekend I'll try to see if installing proprietary ATI code is what breaks the system. Anyway, with proprietary drivers not installed I have an output at full monitor resolution and for Google meet, YouTube and distance learning in general, it's very good. In intensive applications I'm sure taht I'll take a hit in performances, but it's very old anyway, and that is not the purpose of this machine.

Not sure if this can be considered an answer or is merely workaround, but for anyone that has this card (or a card of this generation) maybe can be helpful.